# Yii2 view is not rendered. Returns to home view

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

So I am trying to make a simple register form while I follow this specific guide: https://youtu.be/sRJ6GYiCwkI?t=3122

My problem is that ANY redirect I try to make does not work as intended.

For example, if I need to move to gii my URL must be :

```
> http://localhost:8080/index.php?r=gii%2Fdefault%2Findex
```

Instead of

```
> http://localhost:8080/gii
```

I am using OSX Big Sur and MAMP. Maybe I need to configure something differently?

My log on my terminal when I try to access signup:

```
> [Wed Dec  9 13:33:22 2020] [::1]:51857 [200]: /signup
[Wed Dec  9 13:33:22 2020] [::1]:51858 [200]: /assets/c2edef5c/jquery.js
[Wed Dec  9 13:33:22 2020] [::1]:51859 [200]: /assets/1e2a1c44/yii.js
[Wed Dec  9 13:33:22 2020] [::1]:51860 [200]: /assets/a6d39922/js/bootstrap.js
[Wed Dec  9 13:33:22 2020] [::1]:51861 [200]: /assets/a6d39922/css/bootstrap.css
[Wed Dec  9 13:33:22 2020] [::1]:51862 [200]: /css/site.css
[Wed Dec  9 13:33:22 2020] [::1]:51863 [200]: /index.php?r=debug%2Fdefault%2Ftoolbar&tag=5fd0b60224015
```

When I do the same on XAMPP on Windows 10:

```
> Quit the server with CTRL-C or COMMAND-C.
[Wed Dec  9 13:33:59 2020] PHP 7.4.9 Development Server (http://localhost:8080) started
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63263 Accepted
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63263 [200]: GET /signup
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63263 Closing
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63264 Accepted
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63265 Accepted
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63264 [200]: GET /assets/1f96f9b3/jquery.js
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63266 Accepted
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63265 [200]: GET /assets/87550bf1/yii.js
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63267 Accepted
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63266 [200]: GET /assets/cb962770/js/bootstrap.js
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63268 Accepted
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63267 [200]: GET /assets/cb962770/css/bootstrap.css
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63268 [200]: GET /css/site.css
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63265 Closing
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63264 Closing
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63266 Closing
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63267 Closing
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63268 Closing
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63269 Accepted
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63269 [200]: GET /index.php?r=debug%2Fdefault%2Ftoolbar&tag=5fd0b62fa5773
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63269 Closing
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63270 Accepted
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63270 Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection
[Wed Dec  9 13:34:07 2020] [::1]:63270 Closing
```

My actual script (like the one on the video):

```
    public function  actionSignUp()
{
    $model = new SignupForm();

    //POST DATA
    //PUT INSIDE THE MODEL BASED ON THE RULES OF THE SIGNUP FORM
    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->signup()){
        return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->homeUrl) ;
    }

    return $this->render('signup', [
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}
```

Comment: can you give your `urlManager`

Comment: It is disabled. If I enable it and try to access localhost:8080/signup it still gives me a 404 error

Comment: As i see when there is request of type POST and model signup() works (returns trueish value) you redirect to home url -> so probably works as intendet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bpanatta was correct!

The name was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For using "pretty" urls you should configure your component `urlManager` config, just search for it in your configuration file (`config/web.php` on yii2-basic).

Your configuration should be something like this:

```php
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true, // This must be true
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
    ],
],
```

Also, you need to make shure that your app server (Apache) can handle those requests.

Read more on the Yii2 oficial docs: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#using-pretty-urls

Comment: That indeed fixed my issue. Adding the     >'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager'. However, my signup page still does not work. Can it be an issue with my routes?

Comment: The way you wrote the action name! Try changing from actionSignUp to actionSignup, without the capital "U".
Yii2 parser understands that for accessing this action you should call /sign-up and not /signup